# mySQL - difference between two tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `keywords_by_city` (
  `idKEYWORD` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `CITY` varchar(45) NOT NULL);

CREATE TABLE `city` (
  `idCITY_NAME` varchar(50) NOT NULL DEFAULT ''
);
```

I want to get a list of all the cities in which idKeyword=781 is not present.

I tried creating the query as follows but I don't think its correct:

```
SELECT cty.`idCITY_NAME`
FROM `keywords_by_city` kbc
LEFT JOIN `city` cty ON cty.`idCITY_NAME` = kbc.`CITY`
WHERE kbc.`idKEYWORD` IS NULL
AND kbc.`idKEYWORD` = 781
```

I also tried the following:

```
SELECT `CITY`
FROM `keywords_by_city` kbc
WHERE kbc.`idKEYWORD` = 781
AND kbc.`CITY` NOT IN (SELECT `idCITY_NAME` FROM `city`);
```

neither of these seem to work. Can someone please help. I would prefer a solution without a sub query if possible.

**UPDATE**

I am using the following data:

```
INSERT INTO keywords_by_city (idKEYWORD, CITY)
VALUES (781, 'NYC'), (266855, 'NYC'),
(266856, 'NYC'), (266857, 'NYC'),
(266858, 'NYC'), (266859, 'NYC');

INSERT INTO `city`
(`idCITY_NAME`)
VALUES
('NYC'),('Jersey City'),
('San Jose'),('Albany');
```

Comment: `WHERE kbc.idKEYWORD IS NULL AND kbc.idKEYWORD = 781` This will always return 0 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were close in your attempt. You just needed to swap the tables and put the keyword ID requirement into the join clause:

```
SELECT cty.`idCITY_NAME`
FROM `city` cty
LEFT JOIN `keywords_by_city` kbc ON cty.`idCITY_NAME` = kbc.`CITY` AND kbc.`idKEYWORD` = 781
WHERE kbc.`idKEYWORD` IS NULL
```

Also, it is standard practice to add indices on foreign key fields - ie. `keywords_by_city`.`CITY`. This will make the query perform significantly faster, especially as the table grows.

Answer (score 1):

`t1 LEFT JOIN t2` means t1 table is outer and t2 table is inner of `NESTED LOOP JOIN`

something like this:

```
 foreach (row in t1) {
   if ((t1.col1 matches t2.col1) OR (t1.col1 doest not match t2.col2)) {
     JOIN condition match.
   }
 }
```

so, your query changed like this:

```
SELECT cty.`idCITY_NAME`
FROM `city` cty 
LEFT JOIN `keywords_by_city` kbc
  ON cty.`idCITY_NAME` = kbc.`CITY` AND kbc.`idKEYWORD` = 781 
WHERE kbc.`CITY` IS NULL
```

if you use `INNER JOIN`, the optimizer choose which table is outer using cost function. but `LEFT JOIN` left table is outer in `NESTED LOOP JOIN`, and right table is outer when `RIGHT JOIN`

Comment: I don't get any cities back when I run this query.

Comment: oh, forgive me. I made mistake. but, keep it mind `LEFT JOIN` and left side table is outer in `NESTED LOOP JOIN`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe what you need is:

```
SELECT cty.`idCITY_NAME`
FROM `keywords_by_city` kbc
LEFT JOIN `city` cty ON cty.`idCITY_NAME` = kbc.`CITY`
WHERE kbc.`idKEYWORD` <> 781
```

Comment: This does not seem to work. I have 1616 rows in my city table and 1 row in my `keywords_by_city`table for idKEYWORD=781. I was expecting the query to return 1615 cities in which the keyword is not present.  When I executed the query I got 6 rows back.

Comment: Still does not work. I updated my question to include the data I am using. When I run this query I get back 5 'NYC' rows in the resultset.

I was expecting the resultset to be:
'Jersey City',
'San Jose',
'Albany'

since these are the cities on which 781 is not present

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT idCITY_NAME
FROM city
WHERE idCITY_NAME NOT IN (SELECT CITY FROM keywords_by_city WHERE idKEYWORD != 781)
```

Comment: While this will work, it is very inefficient to pull every city in the sub-select.